# Rails4 gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails' type=select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails' successfully in Rails3. And, it works fine in Rails4 for 'type=text'.

**But, I'm having trouble getting 'type=select' to work.**

Accessory View:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="xeditable" data-emptytext="Type" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-resource="accessories" data-source="/accessorytypes" data-name="accessorytype_id" data-url="/accessories/<%= accessory.id %>" data-original-title="Select Type">
    <%= accessory.accessorytype.name if accessory.accessorytype_id != nil %>
  </a>
</td>
```

Javascript (coffee):

```
  $(".xeditable").editable
    placement: 'bottom'
```

Error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /accessories/5
====================================================

> param is missing or the value is empty: accessory

app/controllers/accessories_controller.rb, line 88
```

Line 88 (Strong Parameters):

```
      params.require(:accessory).permit(:user_id, :manufacturer,:manufacture_year, :model, :accessorytype_id, :description, :sold, :count, :bow_id, :note, :sold_id, :archive)
```

Comment: what's on accessories_controller.rb line 88? the accessory_params call or the render?

Comment: I have line 88 as the last section of my question.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this gem but my guess is you're sending a nil object to the controller action. You could try using the pry gem (or rails 4 equivalent) to place a binding.pry call in that controller action and see what params are being sent across. its prob in the 3rd line of your view. Sry can't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change:

```
From: data-resource="accessories"
To:   data-resource="accessory"
```